# How to get rails & activerecord to manage state across an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application with archive functionality, allowing users to restore objects after they are deleted.

The core functionality has been implemented with the following:

```ruby
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation

  default_scope { where(:archived => false) }

  def self.archived
    unscoped.where(:archived => true)
  end

  def archive
    update(:archived => true)
  end

  def restore
    update(:archived => false)
  end
end

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts

  default_scope { where(:archived => false) }

  def self.archived
    unscoped.where(:archived => true)
  end

  def archive
    update(:archived => true)
  end

  def restore
    update(:archived => false)
  end
end
```

However, support needs to be added for 'cascading' the `archive` and `restore` actions across the `has_many` `belongs_to` association.

The desired rules are as follows:

- **When a contact is archived:** If the contact is the last 'active' contact associated to the organisation then the organisation should also be archived.
- **When a contact is restored:** If the associated organisation is archived then it should also be restored, without restoring any other archived contacts associated to the organisation.
- **When an organisation is archived:** It should archive all of the associated 'active' contacts.
- **When an organisation is restored:** It should restore all contacts which are archived.

How should this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organisation

  default_scope { where(:archived => false) }

  def self.archived
    unscoped.where(:archived => true)
  end

  def archive
    update(:archived => true)
    organisation.archive(all: false) if organisation.contacts.archived.count == organisation.contacts.count
  end

  def restore
    update(:archived => false)
    organisation.restore(all: false) if organisation.archived
  end
end

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts

  default_scope { where(:archived => false) }

  def self.archived
    unscoped.where(:archived => true)
  end

  def archive(all: true)
    update(:archived => true)
    contacts.update_all(:archived => true) if all
  end

  def restore(all: true)
    update(:archived => false)
    contacts.update_all(:archived => false) if all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with this. I haven't tried this yet, but it looks like there could be an issue with restoring a contact from and archived organisation with multiple archived contacts. If you restore a contact from an archived organisation `contact.restore` would call `organisation.restore` which calls `contacts.update_all(:archived => false)`. It looks like this would restore all of the archived contacts within that organisation, which is not the desired result. Any thoughts on how this could be avoided? I'll update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug. updated the answer by adding an additional param. Param name isn't ideal. Perhaps you just replace the `organisation.restore(all: false)` call to `organisation.update(archived: true)`